# Fastest way for a Conditional Column C to be set to either Col A or Col B, based on a conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a ~2MM row dataframe.  I have a problem where, after splitting a column by a delimiter, it looks as though there wasn't a consistent number of columns merged into this split.

To remedy this, I'm attempting to use a conditional new column C where, if a condition is true, should equal column A.  If false, set equal to column B.

**EDIT**:  In attempting a provided solution, I tried some code listed below, but it did not update any rows.  Here is a better example of the dataset that I'm working with:

```
  Scenario meteorology time of day
0      xxx          D7  Bus. Hours
1      yyy          F3    Offshift
2      zzz  Bus. Hours         NaN
3      aaa    Offshift         NaN
4      bbb    Offshift         NaN
```

The first two rows are well-formed.  The Scenario, meteorology, and time of day have been split out from the merged column correctly.  However, on the other rows, the merged column did not have data for meteorology.  Therefore, the 'time of day' data has populated in 'Meteorology', resulting in 'time of day' being nan.

Here was the suggested approach:

```
from dask import dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)
ddf[(ddf.met=='Bus. Hours') | (ddf.met == 'Offshift')]['time'] = ddf['met']
ddf[(ddf.met=='Bus. Hours') | (ddf.met == 'Offshift')]['met'] = np.nan
```

This does not update the appropriate rows in 'time' or 'met'.

I have also tried doing this in pandas:

```
df.loc[(df.met == 'Bus.Hours') | (df.met == 'Offshift'), 'time'] = df['met']
df.loc[(df.met == 'Bus.Hours') | (df.met == 'Offshift'), 'met'] = np.nan
```

This approach runs, but appears to hang indefinitely.

Comment: When you say 2MM rows, do you really mean `2 * (10 ^ 12)` rows ?

Comment: Na people say Million as MM in sales I guess

Comment: @Psidom 2 million (2 * M * M), where M = 1000.  I suppose that would be ~2 ^ 21 rows.

Comment: I don't see why 2 million rows would have a problem with the code you wrote.

Comment: @Psidom - I wouldn't either, but the dang thing has just been sitting there.  Everything else has run ok.  A little afraid to restart it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you are running out of memory and your machine is using disk as temporary memory. That would slow things down for sure, and it's not something smart code can help, I think.

Comment: Even with the largest dfs my 4GB can take, a filter like yours is not as expensive as 20min in CPU time... try a simple test `print(df.loc[(df.A == 2) | (df.A == 1), 'C'])`

Comment: Slightly faster `df.loc[df.A.isin([1, 2]), 'C']`

Comment: Also you seem to be doing the exact complement sets... so maybe initialize with `df.C = df.B` and then run the line for column A... or `df.C = np.where(df.A.isin([1, 2]).values, df.A.values, df.B.values)`

Comment: One concise (and probs more efficient) notation would be: `cond = df.A.isin([1,2]); df.loc[cond, "C"] = df.A; df.loc[~cond, "C"] = df.B`.  If this is taking more than a few seconds, maybe you can post `df.head()` of your actual dataframe so we can help debug

Comment: use `dask`, `dask_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)` then use your conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution was adapted from the comments, and ended up as follows:

```
cond = df.met.isin(['Bus. Hours', 'Offshift'])
df['met'] = np.where(cond, np.nan, df['met'])
df['time'] = np.where(cond, df['met'], df['time'])
```

Came across another situation where this was needed.  It was along the lines of a string that shouldn't contain a substring:

```
df1 = dataset.copy(deep=True)
df1['F_adj'] = 0
cond = (df1['Type'] == 'Delayed Ignition') | ~(df1['Type'].str.contains('Delayed'))
df1['F_adj'] = np.where(cond,df1['F'], 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

try, and calculate time, after all `print(ddf.head(10))` to see output

```
from dask import dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)
ddf[(ddf.A == 2) | (ddf.A == 1)]['C'] = ddf['A']
ddf[(ddf.A != 2) & (ddf.A != 1)]['C'] = ddf['B']

print(ddf.head(x))
```

Comment: This appears to run faster than the speed of light.  I am new to dask.  Do I not need the ".loc" method, and I can reference the target column without a comma inside the brackets as is with pandas?

Comment: @Michael James it's same as iloc, iloc is in pandas only

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far.  I've tried this approach, but the rows do not seem to be updating.  I'm going to update my question with what I've tried here, and some more specific example of the dataset.